# GIT::Is there a command to get the pull requests review comments as a git log?

Tags: git, github

GIT::Is there a command to get the pull requests review comments as a git log ?

Comment: pull requests are not a concept of git. so I'm pretty sure there is no such command.

Comment: If there were such a command, it would be in GitHub’s tool [`hub`](https://github.com/github/hub), which wraps Git and adds GitHub-related commands.